# Removing .php extension from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this code for removing the .php extension from a URL like this: domain.com/file.php to this: domain.com/file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Is there any way to remove the .php extension from domain.com/file.php?action=123456 to domain.com/file?action=123456 ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it already should be so. You can add [QSA] to rule to to double assurance :)

Comment: What it looks like you are trying to do has been solved before many times.  Why reinvent the wheel? First result (of many) in Google for SEO-friendly urls: http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /file\.php\?action=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ file?action=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for those who are wondering, I basically answered my own question. My original code works for all. :)

Answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where did you answer it? You can post the actual working code as an answer. But sentence "it works now" is not an answer.

Comment: @Marki555 I stated "My origninal code works for all." which meant the code I had in the OP works. I should've tested it before I actually asked it lol.

Comment: @edwardjiang7 in that case either delete the whole question or post the code as an answer.